# Subscript out of range

Tags: vba, runtime-error

I'm reaching out because on a works system computer I get run-time errors on basic macros (Excel 2010) Windows Operating System. These errors don't occur on my home Excel 2010, or 2016 systems. I should NOT be getting subscript out of range errors when performing the code in new files.

I wrote these on my own computer without any problems.

```
Option Explicit

Sub MoveDataOtherSheets()

With Excel.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
    Dim cell
    For Each cell In .Range(.Cells(2, 1), Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(Excel.xlUp))

        If cell(1, 1) = "PERSONAL" Then
            With Excel.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4")
                cell.EntireRow.Copy .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(Excel.xlUp)(2, 1)
            End With
        End If

        If cell(1, 1) = "COMPANY" Then
            With Excel.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet5")
                cell.EntireRow.Copy .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(Excel.xlUp)(2, 1)
            End With
        End If
    Next

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: where do you get the error?

Comment: I seem to have pasted twice the same code

Comment: check the workbook the macro resides in actually has worksheets named after "Sheet1", "Sheet2",  "Sheet3",  "Sheet4",  "Sheet5" and  "Sheet6". Moreover you're missing a dot before the 2nd `Cells` occurrence in both `For Each cell In .Range(.Cells(2, 1), Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(Excel.xlUp))` statements

Comment: I noticed that missed the , Dot before cells. But the code on my worklaptop includes that & I'm getting huge issues still. I may need IT to re-install my Microsoft Office Program. Literally, this happens to all sub procedures I write in the program even in newly opened files. The Sheet correspondence in my file is 100% correct.

Comment: I get the array in the project explorer when I'm running the code. It's just a dialog box that states runtime error- subscript out of range. This is not suppose to happen period .

Comment: But it should give you the line where the error occurred, right? Can you even access the cells like you do? I mean as in `cell(i,j)`. shouldn't it be `cell.Value` or `cell.Offset(i,j)` or even `cell.Cells(i,j)`? (Sorry, I just niticed that I forgot to reinstall Office when I wanted to try it out)

Answer (score 0):

As I commented I think the only possible causes of that error are:

- any of the worksheet names you are using is not valid for the actual workbook the running macro resides in (which is `ThisWorkbook` exactly)
- the missing dot in the 2nd occurrence of `Cells` in `For Each cell In .Range(.Cells(2, 1), Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(Excel.xlUp))` statements

  thus while all other references (`.Range` and .`Cells`) are parented to the `object` after the last `With` keyword, the *simple* `Cells(.Rows.Count, 1)` actually refers to the currently active worksheet column 1 last row

but I mostly wrote this answer to propose you some refactoring of your code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub MoveDataOtherSheets()
    Dim cell As Range, dataRng As Range
    Dim shtName As String

    With Excel.ThisWorkbook
        Set dataRng = SetDataRng(.Worksheets("Sheet3"), 1)

        For Each cell In dataRng
            shtName = GetSheetName(cell)
            If shtName <> "" Then CopyRow cell, .Sheets(shtName)
        Next cell
    End With
End Sub

Sub CopyRow(cell As Range, sht As Worksheet)
    With sht
        cell.EntireRow.Copy .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(Excel.xlUp)(2, 1)
    End With
End Sub

Function SetDataRng(sht As Worksheet, colIndex As Long) As Range
    With sht
        Set SetDataRng = .Range(.Cells(2, colIndex), .Cells(.Rows.Count, colIndex).End(Excel.xlUp))
    End With
End Function

Function GetSheetName(cell As Range) As String
    Select Case cell
        Case "PERSONAL"
            GetSheetName = "Sheet4"

        Case "COMPANY"
            GetSheetName = "Sheet5"

        Case Else
            GetSheetName = ""
    End Select
End Function
```

which takes the move from the following considerations:

- it's preferable not to nest `With` blocks referring not *correlatives* objects

  in

  ```
  With Excel.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
     ...
          With Excel.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4")
  ```

  you're nesting two not-parented `With` objects, thus breaking a *sane* `With` "chain" like could be the following:

  ```
  With Excel.ThisWorkbook
      With .Sheets("Sheet3")
      ...
      End With

      With .Sheets("Sheet4")
      ...
      End With
  End With
  ```

  I'm not telling you exactly why this "chain" breaking is *insane* since I learned it quite a long time ago but can't recall now (!), but it has to do with memory management
- avoid putting into `With` blocks code that doesn't use the referenced object

  like that `Dim cell` was
- those two `If` blocks are clearly mutually exclusive: a cell value can't equal "PERSONAL" and "COMPANY" at the same time!

  so the correct `If` block would be:

  ```
  If cell(1, 1) = "PERSONAL" Then
     ....
  ElseIf cell(1, 1) = "COMPANY" Then
     ...
  End If
  ```

  but at this point I'd suggest you to switch to the `Select Case` block construct, which is more suitable for further code branching (should more comparing values arise) and more readable
- it's a good coding habit to demand specific tasks to dedicated Functions/Subs

  this holds true even if these tasks are *up to now* simple and short coded, since the code will *always* grow and quickly become cluttered and hardly comprehensible and maintanable

both the refactoring reasons and the refactored coded are a contribution of mine and are much likely to be improved

but they can be a good starting point

Comment: Thank you very much for the coding suggestions. The new code works perfectly fine on my personal laptop. But on my work computer it generates a Type mismatch error. That's something to do with the runtime program settings because that is not right. The Sub procedure you wrote with the function is crafted 100% right.

Comment: The issue I get is a mismatch when I get to the Function GetSheetName. I'm recognizing the only thing that works on my work laptop is when I'm using modules that references sheet names using integers. It can't recognize sheet names by their property based sheet name ("Sheet1") etc. I've been using Excel for a very long time & this is the first time where a company computer was configured not able to do this procedure.

Comment: What's the language of Excel installation that doesn't recognize "Sheet1" as worksheet name?